# Prepend one constant value to all items of a comma-delimited list

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007, excel-2010, vba

I have two columns. I want to concatenate the cells in ColumnA and ColumnB to give me the output illustrated in ColumnD. I have tried `ColumnA&ColumnB` but the output shown in column C does not correspond to the desired output. How do I fix this?

```
Input1 |Input2  |Output   |Desired output
ColumnA|ColumnB |ColumnC  |ColumnD 
-----------------------------------------
A      |1,2,3,4 |A1,2,3,4 |A1, A2, A3, A4
B      |5,3,6,7 |B5,3,6,7 |B5, B3, B6, B7 
C      |8,9     |C8,9     |C8, C9
D      |10,11,45|D10,11,45|D10, D11, D45
```

Comment: Did you try `ColumnA&ColumnB` as a formula in a cell? Or in VBA? Did you try anything in VBA?

Comment: I am not familiar in VBA i program mostly in shell...

Comment: Did you try `ColumnA&ColumnB` as a formula in a cell? Or in VBA? Did you try anything in VBA?

Comment: I tried ColumnA&ColumnB as a formula.  I tried using MID(B2,FIND(",",B2,1)+1,1) to find the value next to each comma but i am unable to loop through the string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This user-defined function works for me:

```
Function prependToAllElements(prefix As String, commaSeparatedList As String) As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim s() As String
    s = Split(commaSeparatedList, ",")
    For i = LBound(s) To UBound(s)
        s(i) = prefix & s(i)
    Next i
    prependToAllElements = Join(s, ",")
End Function
```

Example usage in cell D1:

```
=prependToAllElements(A1,B1)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this

```
=A1 & SUBSTITUTE(B1;",";", " & A1)
```